# How to read a line with spaces using batch script?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a file called file.txt in which it contains few lines as

```
1.vishnu
2.ram
3.gopal
4.suresh
5.chandra sekar
6.prem kumar
7.nandhu
```

I have written a batch script to read each line and to create a folder and assign the lines as name to that folder.

```
FOR /f "tokens=* delims="  %a in (file.txt) DO @md %a
```

but, the folder created as

```
vishnu
ram
gopal
suresh
chandra
sekar
prem
kumar
nandhu
```

Here the chandra and sekar are seperated as two folders, but i want the chandra sekar as a single folder name, how to acheive this?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense. I would expect `5.chandra` and `sekar` to be created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%A IN (file.txt) DO @md "%%A"
```

Explanation: `FOR`-loop variables use a double-percent `%%`. Also, you need to enclose the filename contained in `%%A` in double quotes, so that it is interpreted as a single directory name, even if it contains spaces. Finally, if you use `"tokens=* delims="`, the directory names that are created will contain the leading numbering as well, i.e. `1.vishnu`, `2.ram` and so on.